# No ending delimiter. PHP

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть входная строка, которую нужно определить либо в латинский массив, либо в кириллический.
Вот так я проверяю на то, какие символы содержит строка и определяю язык:

```
if(preg_match("^\p{Latin}+$", $key)){
        array_push($en, $key);
    }
    else{
        array_push($ru, $key);
    }
```

Но мне прилетает следующий warning: `PHP Warning:  preg_match(): No ending delimiter '^'`.
Подскажите где косяк.

Comment: Так добавьте разделители - `preg_match("~^\p{Latin}+$~", $key)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, зато сейчас стало выбрасывать исключение [EA] /u modifier is missing (unicode codepoints found). Хоть я и изменил руглярку на "~^\p{Latin}+$/u~"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Регулярные выражения в PHP необходимо использовать внутри [**разделителей**](http://php.net/manual/ru/regexp.reference.delimiters.php). Это либо парные символы (кавычки, скобки), либо какой-нибудь символ (часто используют обратный слеш, так как только этот символ используется в JavaScript, и многие к нему привыкли).

В данном случае выражение `^\p{Latin}+$` не содержит разделителей, однако символ `^` (здесь обозначающий начало строки) был определён PHP как начальный разделитель, а соответственно, PHP ожидал этот же символ в конце строки. Так как его там нет, PHP выдаёт ошибку.

Используйте разделители, а также модификатор `u` в данном случае, так как вы работаете не только с символами ASCII:

```
$key = "WiktorStribiżew";
if(preg_match("~^\p{Latin}+$~u", $key)){
  echo "$key is valid!";
} else {
  echo "$key is invalid!";
}
// => WiktorStribiżew is valid!
```

См. [пример работы кода на PHP](https://3v4l.org/liWY8). Тут разделители `~`.